# How to I specify a primary key for Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My server uses `sensorID` as the primary key on my `Sensor` model. I've tried the following

```
App.SensorSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: "sensorID"
});
```

based on what I see in [this test](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/fb8a611baffb1707e880419964bd60b85c1f4241/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/adapter/rest_adapter_test.js#L113), but it's not working. I'm getting an error:

```
Error while loading route: Error: No model was found for '0'
```

I'm using a custom adapter. The response is JSONP:

```
jQuery203041337518650107086_1397489458691([{"sensorID":1,"address":"XXX, YYY","latitude":"nnnn","longitude":"mmmm"...
```

but when I inspect the data that gets returned, it's a normal array:

```
// App.SensorAdapter
findAll: function(store, type, sinceToken) {
  var url = 'http://blahblahblah/?callback=?';
  var query = { since: sinceToken };

  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    jQuery.getJSON(url, query).then(function(data) {
      debugger;
      // data.forEach(function(s) {
      //   s.id = +s.sensorID;
      // });
      Ember.run(null, resolve, data);

    }, function(jqXHR) {
      jqXHR.then = null; // tame jQuery's ill mannered promises
      Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
    });
  });
```

What is the correct syntax for Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.7?

Comment: Will you show the json you're receiving, it's likely you have an attribute `0` which ED is trying to find the model for.

Comment: that's only a portion of the json, but here's the link to the transition documentation explaining the proper format, https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
App.Adapter.map('App.Sensor', {
  primaryKey: 'sensorID'
});
```